# Ubuntu 12.04 on Vm Player showing Wired Network Instead of Wireless Network

Tags: wireless, vmware

I am new to Ubuntu, recently I installed ubuntu 12.04 in Vm Player (Virtual Machine) on my Dell laptop having windows 7 ultimate 32 bit for just to check the security of my wireless network and want to crack the WiFi (WPA-PSK) password but in ubuntu it does not show the wireless network it shows the 2 arrow sign as i have not connect the ethernet cable to my laptop and connected through WiFi on my main OS (windows 7) but it shows the wired network and internet is working but it does not show wifi connection. On windows 7 WiFi is connected and showing the WiFi connection and working correctly.But my main motive is to crack the WiFi password as it can't detect WiFi network so what to do?  Please Help.!!thanks

My Laptop Specification :

Laptop       :  Dell Latitude D620

OS           :  Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit

Processor    :  Core Duo 2 T7200 @ 2Ghz

Ram          :  2 GB

WiFi card    :  Intel Pro/Wireless 3945 ABG

Virtual
 Machine      :  Vm Player V 5.0.1

If Need to Install Drivers Please Give Me Full Information how to install and which driver I should install. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: If Ubuntu is running inside a virtual machine, then it will typically not see actual hardware but fake hardware provided by the VM, which usually includes a fake wired network card which provides a bridged connection to the network. I suspect WEP/WPA cracking requires low-level access to the real hardware which will not be possible from within a VM.

Answer (score 2):

From within the perspective of a virtual machine, you'll see the virtualized (emulated) hardware, not your real hardware. The hypervisor (VMware player in your case) will emulate a whole machine in which your Ubuntu installation is running. Specifically, VMware emulates a new network device (you can see that in Windows device manager) and will *route* traffic on IP-level, or bridge on Ethernet-level. It won't pass the whole device.

You have several options to gain access to your wireless hardware in Ubuntu:

- Install Ubuntu (native) on your machine. Any way will be sufficient: Wubi install, dual boot, or on an external hard drive.
- Run Ubuntu from the Live CD. This limits you from receiving possibly needed updates, and you'll loose all changes on every reboot.
- Using a passthrough technology like Intel VT-d which allows you to redirect all low-level hardware calls to a virtual machine. This will make the hardware unavailable in your host operating system. However, your hardware does not support this, and that's why I don't recommend you to try this.
- Find a USB Wireless card and use USB redirection with that device instead. I'm not sure if that's available in VMware Player, but if it is, this is possible without specific hardware support.

Answer (score -2):

try reinstalling the network manager: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager`